# how to update cache in java spring framework on creating new entry

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Create user function:

```
@Autowired private org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager;
public boolean createUser(Users user,HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("cache update changed");
    Cache c = cacheManager.getCache("defaultCache");
    if (c != null) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        c.put("",user.getUsername()); 
        // this code is not working 
    }

    //BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(user);

    MapSqlParameterSource params=new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("username", user.getUsername());
    params.addValue("user_session_id", session.getId());
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    //params.addValue("message_time",new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime()));

    params.addValue("user_last_activity_time", new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime()));

    jdbc.update("insert into users (username,user_session_id,user_last_activity_time) values (:username,:user_session_id,:user_last_activity_time)", params);// == 1;

    //c.clear();
    //return user;
    return true;
}
```

Get user function:

```
@Cacheable(value="defaultCache")
//@CachePut(value="defaultCache")
public List<Users> getOnlineUsers() {
    System.out.println("DB Query");
    return jdbc.query(sql, new RowMapper<Users>() {
        @Override
        public Users mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNumb) throws SQLException {
            Users user = new Users();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            return user;
        }
    });
}
```

please help me how can I update the cache on creating new user so when I get users from `List<Users> getOnlineUsers()` function by jquery json function i should get updated cache. Thanks

Comment: Format your code first.

Comment: you cache contains a list of users and you try to "put" some username inside..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to clear complete cache using `@CacheEvict` then you can use `allEntries = true` in annotation parameter

```
@CacheEvict(value="defaultCache",  allEntries = true) 
public boolean createUser(Users user, HttpSession session) { ....
```

Answer (score 3):

The exact way of doing this will depend on the cost of loading all users and the number of times users get created.

You basically have two options:

- *Invalidation based*: Do not update the cache when creating a user, instead invalidate the mapping. Since you are using Spring, I recommend doing that through the [Spring caching annotation `@CacheEvict`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-evict) so that it happens outside of the transaction that created the user.
- *Manual*: Keep going on the path you started, but there what you have to do is get the collection of users from the cache and add you new `User` to it. And then put that mapping back in the cache. For that you will need to figure out what Spring caching uses as default key, or specify a key in your `@Cacheable` annotation on `getOnlineUsers`.

Comment: Expand your question with what you tried then. Without details, hard to say what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

you also can use @CachePut on the method which creates the new entry. The return type has to be the same as in your @Cachable method.

```
@Service
public class CacheService {

  public static final String KEY = "THE_KEY";

  @CachePut(cacheNames = {"defaultCache"}, key = "#root.target.KEY")
  public List<Users> createUser {
  // create user and return all users
   ...
   } 

  @Cacheable(cacheNames = {"defaultCache"}, key = "#root.target.KEY")
  public List<Users> getOnlineUsers() {
  // return all users
   ...
   } 
}
```

As you can see I also use cacheNames and and a key for the key. Normalwise you use parametes of the method for the key. In case of different parameters or no parameters you can use the version here with 'public static final' key.

Inject the Service where you need it and call the methods.

```
@Autowire
CacheService cacheService;

...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [`@CacheEvict`](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-0) annotation.

```
@CacheEvict("defaultCache")
public boolean createUser(Users user, HttpSession session) {
....
```

Comment: i already tried annotation @CacheEvict its not working..it still cache stale cache

Comment: You need to modify the code as @CacheEvict("defaultCache", allEntries = true)